# Unable to reach app. Please try again on Adaptive card in v4 VA

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

[image][image][image][image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]]MSFT

I try to implement Task module in Ms team to open external app/url in pop up module. 1st, I tried task module sample code and get below error while using ngrok or after deployment on azure as well.

Error:

1. Something went wrong after clicking any of button in attached screenshot.
2. Unable to reach app. Please try again.

I raised same question in Github on below thread.

https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3701

[Sample code task module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7uY0.png)

Could you please help me here to achieve this feature? if, it is not supporting as per github, please do let us know an idea by when it will release.

Thanks
Singh

Comment: Hi @upendra We could not repro the issue on our side. Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module)? Try if that helps

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT, did you see below github url ? I am facing same problem.https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3701

Comment: Yes i have checked the git-hub URL. Did you try the sample which i have provided are you facing the issue with the sample also? Could you please share your app manifest?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT,  I am using same as provided my Microsoft and attached in original question. I have include all things in my existing for client but getting same issue for both. Repo steps are very sample: I download TaskModuleCsharp.zip file from below url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp/ms-teams-task-sample/ and install in app studio. it is accessible from installed machine/server sometimes (1/10) but it is not working for other users on same domain.

Comment: I have tested the sample, Not able to repro the issue on our side. Here is the screen shot of the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY1BM.png). Could you please share console logs?

Comment: Please find console log in original question: I don't know , how to add screen shot here.

Comment: From the screen shot i could see that there is no tab for the app but in the manifest there is a static tab, Did you install the bot? Could you please try by installing the manifest in the sample?

Comment: Yes, I installed sample manifest file only.

Comment: But in the screen shot it does not look you have installed the manifest file there is no tab.
Could you please follow the steps to install the manifest?
Step 1: click on the three dots select more apps as shown
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKI8X.png)
Step 2: upload the manifest zip file usinng upload custom app as shown:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA1iI.png)
Step3: Add the app
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub65U.png)

Comment: hi @Nikitha-MSFT,  I followed same steps multiple times and getting same issue, I am attaching console log in original question again, still getting same problem.

Comment: One more repo steps: I installed same manefest.zip package  using one Id like (upendra.singh@XXdemo.net), if access bot from same msteam channel sometimes (2/10). it was open pop up model but if I or my team try it from (upendra.singh@XXX.com) . it is throwing error.  which i attached console log in original question. If you can try at your end in same way it will be reproduced at your end.   In above scenarios our existing bot is working on production.

Comment: From the screen shot it does not look you have installed the manifest. When you install the manifest which is specified in the sample it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtCl2.png). Could you please check the steps which i have mentioned and try it again?

Comment: HI Nikitha-MSFT,  did you get a chance to reproduce my previous steps? Screen shot which  you  shared  it will comes, only the machine where it get installed  not for other users. It is a major problem in Task Module at MS . Please do let me know when it will work for all users with out failing.

Comment: Could you please send an email to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com?

Comment: sure, i am sending mail along with repo steps.

Answer (score 3):

Errors like these are often related to the domain you're trying to reach (in this case a temporary ngrok one) not being registered in the app's manifest as "valid" domains. Try add it, re-upload the manifest, deploy the app again, and test. Presumably you're using App Studio, so you should "delete" the existing one, and re-upload the modified version (or just make the modifications directly in App Studio and redeploy)

Comment: I have followed all steps but still getting same issues.

Comment: are you able to share your app manifest? Hide anything you don't want public - I need to see the concepts but not every single 'secret' you might have in there (like bot IDs)

Comment: I am using same as provided by Microsoft and also created created same way for our client. but I am getting same error in both application. I have attached .png in original question. I just down load it and import in appstudios. Some time it was access at same place (installed machine) but is not accessible for other users on same domain.  If you want I can share my menifest.json but it is same as provided by Microsoft. please help here, my client is crazy to see BT Chat in pop up model.

Comment: Can you link to the original one from Microsoft - the link to the original project you're testing with, I'll try check it out my side. Or is the one Nikitha linked to?

Comment: yes, please find below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp/ms-teams-task-sample/

Comment: Can confirm that this also only happens to me when running it locally with ngrok, but never when deployed.